# How to integrate Jasper Report with ADF and jDeveloper 11g?

Tags: jasper-reports

I made ​​a report with Jasper iReport Designer and don't know how to integrate that report with ADF and jDeveloper 11g and run it.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know if you fixed this but you may go through this link. It is a full tutorial and in the end gives the test application: 
http://sameh-nassar.blogspot.com/2012/12/using-jasper-report-in-adf-application.html